# PHP : file_get_contents($loc) fails

Tags: php

I just moved a project from localhost over to my remote server, and noticed that some of my scripts stopped working. Most importantly was one that relied upon `file_get_contents()` to fetch JSON values from another script.

PHP Version is 5.2.4
`allow_url_fopen` is ON

> Warning: `file_get_contents()` `[function.file-get-contents]`: `php_network_getaddresses`: `getaddrinfo` failed: Name or service not known in `/var/www/html/2009/functions/functions.products.php` on `line 5`
>
> Warning: `file_get_contents(http://data.example.com/new-data.php) [function.file-get-contents]`: failed to open stream: `Success in /var/www/html/2009/functions/functions.products.php` on `line 5`

The script is being ran from: `http://www.example.com`
The location passed into the function is `http://data.example.com/new-data.php`

**Note**: Same domain name, but two different servers.

```php
function getData() {
  $location = "http://data.mysite.com/new-data.php";
  $contents = file_get_contents($location);
  $jsonVars = json_decode($contents);
  return $jsonVars
}
```

Comment: There has to be an error in your error log somewhere or something returned. Need more info.

Comment: If new-data.php is on the same server as the script calling it, why aren't you just passing the path to it instead of a URL?

Comment: Also, do you have error_reporting(E_ALL);?

Comment: @Paolo, yes, I have error_reporting(E_ALL). The script is not on the same server, no.

Comment: Is display_errors also enabled?

Comment: @Gumbo, no, it wasn't. I've got a warning now. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Name or service not known

DNS is broke. Can you `ping data.mysite.com` from a shell on the machine (assuming you have one)?

Try replacing `data.mysite.com` with a fixed IP address for now.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Couldn't find it.

Comment: Can you access *any* site by name from the server? eg. `ping google.com`. If not, probably you're missing some nameserver settings in /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: This was it. I just had to replace the URL with the IP Address. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest fixing the DNS problem and not rely on hard-coding IP addresses into the code. Depending on your hosting situation, you may be bypassing some load-balancing or fault-tolerant routing configuration. Also, it will be easier to make changes in the future or even be host-independent.

Comment: Best way for me. Did it with `exec()`.

Comment: Same happened to me. I've a VM running an apache server that use to work. The problem was that my VM hasn't got internet access.

Answer (score 7):

Also you can try curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://url.url');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

And you get what you want in `$result`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your /etc/hosts on the remote server.  If it's empty, you need to add '127.0.0.1 localhost' to it.

Unless it's one of the varieties of VPS where the loopback interface hits the outer machine; on those, you need to use your VPS's IP number instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Localhost (LH), New Host (NH), and Data-Provider (DP). Those are my three machines involved. LH could get the data from DP, but NH cannot. Are you saying I need to check /etc/hosts of NH or DP?

Comment: for VM add to /etc/hosts  all subdomains :
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 subdomain1.localhost    localhost
127.0.0.1 subdomain2.localhost    localhost

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure it is not a DNS issue, try restarting Apache. This solved it for me after 20 minutes of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

Please include more information, does $contents contain anything? Remember to do json_decode($contents, true) if you want it as a php array otherwise its a stdClass that gets returned.

Could it have a problem resolving the hostname? is data.mysite.com the same machine as mysite.com?