# PHP: file_get_contents() gives me "Name or service not known"

Tags: php, nginx, dns, file-get-contents

Okay, this question has been asked plenty of times around the internet, but I haven't found any solution that fixes the problem in my case.

I'm about to fetch some JSON data with this code:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/path/to/json');
```

And it's constantly stumbling over the following error:

> file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known

I'm running **Debian** with **PHP 5.4.4** on **Nginx 1.2.6** and **php-fpm**.

This is my troubleshooting so far:

1. The URL exists and gives a valid result in the browser.
2. I've ensured that `allow_url_fopen` is on in php.ini.
3. I've changed to Google Public DNS in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
4. Doing `ping google.com` works.
5. Switching to `http://0.0.0.0/path/to/json` works but is undesirable.
6. I've got a couple of domains pointing to the same server, and the same problem occurs independently.

I'm a bit concerned about the `domain` in `/etc/resolv.conf`, is it right?

```
# Automatically generated by OnApp (2.3.0-29)
domain localdomain

# Original DNS
#nameserver 10.0.10.10
#nameserver 10.0.11.11

# Google Public DNS
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it just `localdomain` or the actual domain?

Comment: what happens if you use the domain ip ?

Comment: @AmalMurali It's just `localdomain`

Comment: What is the real URL, do you mind pasting it in your question?

Comment: @srain: It's from Google Maps API, and it's valid.

Comment: Your problem solved? If not, this may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210099/php-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-no-such-host-is-known

Comment: Hi, Ivar, did you get it solved? If so please let us know the solution.

Comment: Hey @Muktadir, yeah I got it solved, see my accepted answer. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : file\_get\_contents($loc) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542046/php-file-get-contentsloc-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say this, but the problem solved itself; I just upgraded the Debian packages (`apt-get upgrade`) and the problem went away. Frustrating to not know the cause, though.

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a DNS problem. If IP works but domain has problems you should look into the DNS. That's what "name or service not known" hints to.
If you can, use different nameservers. I think google's dns can't translate your domain to the ip.

Comment: But there was no difference when I switched from the original nameservers to the Google Public DNS. Do you recommend any other nameserver?

Comment: Can you use whois and dig to see what they tell you? Post it here as well.
`dig yourwebsite.com @ns1.yourdnsserver.com`

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved in two ways, either run php (or apache) in root user mode or update your debian package. It's probably debian7u5 or update 4 who has this bug.