# php file_get_content /curl no response

Tags: php, apache, curl, server, file-get-contents

i am trying to use googles geoloacating api with php: file_get_content.

This works fine on my testsystem but it wont work live. The code is excatly the same and the servers are also the same. I got some errormails like:

> file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   Name or service not known

allow_url_fopen is available and curl is also available.

I alsso tryed the same with curl but the result was the same live didnt work.

Hope some of you can give me some tips.

Comment: Looks like a DNS problem. What server are you using? Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi

Comment: Try to restart your apache web server and see.

Comment: Which url are you trying to get?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com Apache is not involved here. The error comes from the OS' services. It's a DNS lookup failure.

Comment: i tryed to connect to :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/

It's not my own server so i cant restart it.