# Updating PHP errors due to php_network_getaddresses failed error

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

So this morning I discover my website payment forms where breaking and on further investigation I discovered that it would appear that my server (Ubuntu 14.4)  is unable to connect to the outside world, namely:

**Running from CLI:**

```
$php composer.phar self-update
```

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>   The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known     failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known

**or a dig:**

```
$ dig www.google.com
```

> ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> www.google.com ;; global
>   options: +cmd ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

**Apache:**

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'
```

Similar posts on stack: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi) would suggest I change name servers...

So I am thinking that I should set up the server to use googles name servers:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

How is this done on Ubuntu 14.4 ?

Comment: Although it's off-topic: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` then add name servers, one per line: `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, `nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Comment: Thanks for the effort, that has been set. The problem it turns out is that the IP range is under a DDOS attack and the DataCenter has mitigated the traffic to that IP range... hence why we are unable to view the outside world...