# can someone help me with me PHP image scraper?

Tags: php, html, arrays, image, scraper

When I do one website at once it works just fine but when I do more at a time I get the following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Host is onbekend. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blabla\simple_html_dom.php on line 76
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.nl ): failed to open
>   stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host is
>   onbekend. in C:\xampp\htdocs\blabla\simple_html_dom.php on line 76
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blabla\backend.php on line 21

### This is my image scraper:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $notes = explode("\n", $_POST['linkjes']);

        foreach ($notes as $link) {
            x($link);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "je hoort hier niet";
    }


    function x($link){

    $file = 'images.txt';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html($link);

    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)

        if (strpos($element->src,'.png') !== false) 
        {
            $current .= $element->src."\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
         } 
         else if (strpos($element->src,'.jpg') !== false) 
         {
            $current .= $element->src."\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
         } 
         else if (strpos($element->src,'.gif') !== false) 
         {
                $current .= $element->src."\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
         }
         else if (strpos($element->src,'.ico') !== false) 
         {
                $current .= $element->src."\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
         }
         else if (strpos($element->src,'.jpeg') !== false) 
         {
                $current .= $element->src."\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
         }

    $lines = file($file);
    $lines = array_unique($lines);
    file_put_contents($file, implode($lines));

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `simple_html_dom.php` - I suppose this is 3rd party library. To answer your question we should see the source code of this library, due to the fact that we do not know the versions of library you use

Comment: did you check for similar issues with that error? If not, please do. If you did, please add how that didn't help, e.g. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to PHP (or arrays). According to Google Translator, "onbekend" is a Dutch word that means "unknown". Does your server have full internet connectivity?

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ this is the source of simple_html_dom.php