# file_get_contents() PHP function not working on windows server running apache

Tags: php, windows, file, base64

So I have a server running windows on it, which is running a PHP environment to run a blog website.

Now the following code runs fine on my localhost using xampp, but does not work on the windows server.

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postId, array(150,150));
$ext = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
```

The code gets the post thumbnail from the loop and creates a base64 image, which I use in a blur up image technique(Like what happens to the first two images [on this site](http://www.theiconic.com.au/))

When I echo out the `$ext` and `$image` variables I get data, but when I echo the `file_get_contents($image)` I get nothing. I can confirm the file does exist.

```
echo $ext . ':' . $image;
echo '<br />' . file_get_contents($image);
```

I came across the suggestion to `allow_url_fopen` but when I check by echoing out `phpinfo()` it is enabled

```
echo  phpinfo();
```

The php version is 5.6 so that wouldn't be the problem either.

Also when I turn wordpress debug on for the windows server I get this error: Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Anyone know of other potential causes for this preblom.
Cheers

[image]

Comment: Is there a valid url in the `$image` variable? Is there actually a domain that exists at that address? That error usually means the URL doesn't exist or can't be found.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks for the help. The image does exist. when I copy the output from the image variable and paste into my browser it works

Comment: `getaddrinfo` is a system function unrelated to php except for the fact that php uses it like many other programs do. Can you ping the domain from the server?

Comment: A lot of stack questions come up if you google that error message. It looks like most of them point to DNS issues. Here's one that looks pretty popular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi

Comment: Nope not DNS issue, see my answer. I looked at those answers but to no avail. Thanks @JonathanKuhn & Don'tPanic for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg so I figured it out.

The windows server is a test site, with url https://test.domain.com.au
So is a subdomain.

So when I updated my code to replace the test with www in the url, it works.

```
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents(str_replace('test', 'www', $image)));
```

So even though the image url https://test.domain.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/my-image-150x150.jpg is a valid url and was displaying an image when pasted into the browser address bar, the `file_get_contents()` function didn't like it.

Not sure why this is as the test site is a live site, so live as in on the internet.

I hope this helps someone else :)