# Google ReCaptcha : Name or service not known

Tags: php, recaptcha

When trying to add a reCaptcha on my contact form, i get this error :

> Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in *******/MyClass.php on line 79

```
$secret = "*********************";
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$api_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secret. "&response=" . $response. "&remoteip=" . $remoteip ;
$decode = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true);
```

Line 79 is "$decode = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true);"
I have checked my php.ini, allow_url_fopen = ON.
So .. can't figure out what is wrong. Any idea ?

Comment: What's the output of `print_r(gethostbyname('www.google.com'));` ?

Comment: @EduardoEscobar It's "www.google.com"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi

Comment: @j08691Hmm ok so according to you it's an "infrastructure" issue ? I'm going to share it with my sysadmin

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with DNS settings for a while before discovering http just needed a restart to kick php:

```
service httpd restart
```

recaptcha works again now.