# file_get_content() : "No such file or directory" behind a proxy

Tags: php, http, proxy

I'm trying to fetch data from the Internet using PHP. Being at work, I'm behind a password protected proxy which seems to cause trouble.

I have consulted many posts on StackOverflow and several other platforms, each one giving me a different solution, none of which could fill my needs.

```
var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());

$opts = array("http" => ['proxy'=>'user:password@webproxy.xxx.intra:####',
                        'request_fulluri' => True]
        );

stream_context_set_default($opts);

$homepage = file_get_contents("www.google.com");
echo $homepage;
```

I've added `var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());` as advised in one of the posts I've previously read, returning : ***[https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip]***

And the warning I get is the following :

> PHP Warning: file_get_contents(www.google.com): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in /home/user/project/app/connector.php on line 15

Line 15 being `$homepage = file_get_contents("www.google.com");`

I've been stuck there for way too long, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT :** I have added "http://" to the beginning of the address, giving me this error :

> PHP Warning: file_get_contents(google.com): failed to open stream:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known in /home/user/project/app/connector.php on line 15

For some reason this error got displayed twice, the second one being almost the same with less information.

Comment: `www.google.com` is actually a filename, which really doesn't exist. If you want to perform an HTTP request, make sure the URI starts with that scheme.

Comment: I don't think www.google.com is a valid file name..?

Comment: @CodeCaster what scheme ? http:// ?
That's what I get in return : _PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.google.com): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/user/project/app/connector.php on line 15_

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer I'm new to PHP in general and I don't really know what I should do. I get that 'www.google.com' isn't a valid file, but how can I fetch the contents of the site then ?

Comment: Yeah so that's a new error. What did your research for that error show? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer it's a perfectly valid filename on all filesystems I know, barring FAT16. A file with that name just doesn't exist, hence the error.

Comment: I think you are looking for web scraping thing like to get data from URL, If yes try this link it would help http://www.oooff.com/php-scripts/basic-php-scraped-data-parsing/basic-php-data-parsing.php

Comment: I think you are looking for web scraping thing like to get data from URL, If yes try this [link](http://www.oooff.com/php-scripts/basic-php-scraped-data-parsing/basic-php-data-parsing.php) it would help

Comment: @CodeCaster I was reading the same post you linked, but I really do not think I can do much by myself. I'll try and figure my way out with the tech support at work. Thanks for your time and help !

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer actually, the main goal of these lines was just to test whether or not PHP is able to access the Internet. I'm working on something else which requires it.

Answer (score 0):

After searching even more, here is what I have come up with :

```
$auth = base64_encode('login:password');

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://proxy_host:proxy_port',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
        'header' => "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth",
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com", False, $context);
echo $file;
```

This seems to work fine.
Thanks for your help and advices.