# PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, file-get-contents

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in
>   /home/public_htm/xD.php on line 23 PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(http://google.com in /home/public_htm/xD.php on line
>   23

**Does anyone know tell me how to fix this error?**

line 23 = $html2 = file_get_contents($code);

**I need to be *$code*
instead url fixed**

Comment: takes a correction for this code php , you can tell me an alternative code or something the genre ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386364/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed