# file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Out of the blue I started receiving this error whenever I tried to use file_get_contents (or curl).

I run Nginx on Ubuntu, and I believe it's an issue in Nginx, because if I try to run the same file from the server (php file.php), it works perfectly.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the permissions on the file haven't changed?

Comment: Hi, I've just tried changing the permissions to 777. Still same error.

Comment: So the file itself is loading fine, from the server its hosted on. But trying to get its contents from an external server is where it's failing, yes? How are you calling it? Via an IP or a domain name?

Comment: Well for example I just do something as simple as `echo file_get_contents('https://google.com');`

Comment: Oh, so it's not loading anything? Not just a specific file?

Comment: The problem is with every web page.

Comment: Hard to say. It could be a DNS issue, if nginx is using a different set of nameservers? I assume you've tried obvious things like restarting nginx? Have you tried these things: http://serverfault.com/questions/612992/nginx-and-php-cant-resolve-hostname-and-make-connection-with-fqdn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP : file\_get\_contents($loc) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542046/php-file-get-contentsloc-fails)

Answer (score 2):

Just happened the same to me on Ububntu + Apache.
Restarted the server and it magically just fixed the issue.

Comment: thank you! just met this issue. restarted the server and it's fixed. haha don't know why. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Restarting will fix it temporarily, but it will come back. An update caused this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue on two different servers.

For me restarting PHP resolved the issue (temporarily).

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

I'm affected about once a day by the problem. Therefore I set up a cronjob to restart PHP every hour. I hope there will be a real fix as soon as possible.

My environment:
Ubuntu 16.04 @AWS EC2
PHP 7.0

MySQL 5.6 @AWS RDS